# What is the difference? + Select + Option + jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

This code shows an alert with the option selected and works good!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select#combo').on('change', function() {
            var valor = $(this).val();
            alert(valor);
        });
    });
</script>

<select id="combo">
    <option value="1">Hola</option>
    <option value="2">Hola2</option>
    <option value="3">Hola3</option>
</select>
```

The next code prints a "select" in the page with jQuery.
So, the question is: If the next code is the same, why this code doesn't show the alert?.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#result").click(function() {
            var correos = '<select name="combo" id="combo">';
            correos = correos + '<option value="0" selected="selected">Seleccionaalgo</option>';
            correos = correos + '<option value="1">Hola</option>';
            correos = correos + '<option value="99">Todos</option>';
            correos = correos + '</select>';
            $("#resultado").html(correos);
        });
        $('select#combo').on('change', function() {
            var valor = $(this).val();
            alert(valor);
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="resultado"></div>
<div id="result" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: green;">Click me!</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically created elements:

```
 $(document).on('change', 'select#combo' , function() {
     var valor = $(this).val();
     alert(valor);
 });
```

Btw, `id` should be unique, you must use class instead.